# Netbeans Web Service Client can not be created by JAXWS:wsimport utility

Tags: java, netbeans, soap

Estoy intentando consumir un servicio web desde netbeans 8.1 y me arroja el siguiente error:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

He testeado desde SoapUI y parece estar bien:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

No se cual puede ser el problema, si alguien sabe que puede estar pasando

Gracias.

Comment: Buenos Días He tenido el mismo problema y veo que no hay respuesta. Pudiste solucionar tu incoveniente ?? Como lo hiciste ? Gracias.

Comment: Hola desde el netbeans no pude solucionarlo, intente con eclipse, me llega a generar las clases y métodos, a que servicio te estás conectando?

Comment: Con el intellij puedes probar también

Answer (score 0):

Ve a xml-resources de tu proyecto, abre el archivo *billService.wsdl* y busca la etiqueta *wsdl:import*. Dentro cambia *billService?ns1.wsdl* por ***billService.ns1.wsdl***, guardas los cambios y dale refresh al billService.